# Granting permissions to all tables of a db

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I want to grant select permissions to a newly created user over all tables of a postgres db (version 8.4). I can't use GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES as it is not supported in 8.4 . I have to provide individual table names in this query -

GRANT SELECT ON tab1, tab2, tab3 TO foo;

The number of tables is too large to be individually named.
Is there any script I could execute that will help my case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293732/how-do-i-grant-certain-privileges-to-all-tables-in-a-database

Comment: Why are you using an outdated and un-maintained version?